# Freeing a reference vs freeing a pointer? Can we tell whether an argument is a reference or a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have a structure, like

```
 typedef struct {
    void* data;
    int index;
 } Node;
```

and I have some lines like

```
 Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
 enqueue(&list, node);
```

Then I have a function:

```
delete_node(Node* node) {
   free(node->data);
   free(node);
}
```

Consider `free(node->data);`. If `data` is a pointer to a heap data, that's fine, but if it is a reference then there is a problem. How would I deal with this? (The tags already make it obvious, but just to emphasize it: This is not a C++ question.)

Comment: What do you mean by `data` being a reference?  It might help if you posted a complete code example that demonstrates this.

Comment: Just think about your semantics beforehand, and then stick to that.

Comment: consider if this is a template. For example, long x=100; node->data = &x;

Comment: Operation such as to unify the heap is required because it is thought that it isn't possible to distinguish.

Comment: `unify` the heap? what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, C has no references, so let's stop using that particular term.

What I believe you're asking is how can you know whether a pointer points to something allocated by `malloc` (or one of its cousins), or an object allocated with automatic storage duration.

The answer is; you can't.  Provide a function for allocating `node`s and document that these functions must be used.  If they are not and a client passes in, say, a pointer to a local, the behavior is undefined. So, you have something like...

```
node *alloc_node(size_t size);
void  free_node(node *node);
```

If I pass a `Node*` to `free_node` which was not allocated with `alloc_node`, the behavior is undefined and it's my fault.  This is a very common idiom in C.

Think about it; `free` has the same problem, right?  You could certainly do something like:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    free(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Well, `free` doesn't care.  Even if it did there's nothing (sane) that it could do to detect this situation.  The onus is on you (us). If you use it in a way in which it is not intended to be used, the behavior is undefined and you get what you deserve.

Answer (score 0):

There's no (portable) way to tell if a pointer is pointing to memory allocated through `malloc` or to a `static` or `auto` variable.  You will need to design your code such that the `data` member is only ever assigned the result of a `malloc` call.